# problems with converting sql statement to linq-to-sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm new to Entity Framework.

I have  3  tables.

```
Candidats : Id,cin
Poste : Id
PosteCandidats : candidat_id, poste_id
```

I want to get a candidat that has (cin= 'abc15' and poste_id = 3)

I tried this but it gives me an error

```
select * from  Candidats where 
id=(select Candidat_Id from PosteCandidats where Poste_Id=3)
and num_cin='abc15';
```

After that I want to convert it to Linq query.

Edit :

My models :

```
public class Candidat
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string num_cin    { set; get; }
    public ICollection<Poste> postes { get; set; }
}

public class Poste
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string poste_name {set;get}
    public List<Candidat> candidats {set;get;}
}
```

That generates an association table PosteCandidats.

Comment: The code you showed is tsql not linq query. Have you tried the linq query so far?

Comment: yes i know  because  it's not working  !!  my goal is to have it  in  lin  query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linq query can look like this.

```
var myEntities = ...; // db context

var query = myEntities.Candidats
                .Where(c => c.num_cin == "abc15" 
                && c.Postes.Any(pc => pc.Id == 3))
var candidat = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it gives me  that   PosteCandidats   not   exist  in   myEntities  DB context   (because  it  an  association table  !!! )

Comment: post your models, I can't just imagining your classes structure without seeing the code !!!

Comment: @saidmohamed11, are you sure that's the correct models? `Candidat` has list of `Candidat` ? Shouldn't it be list of `Poste` ?

Comment: @saidmohamed11, I changed the answer as well